# React native socket io no events being emitted from client

Tags: ios, node.js, socket.io, react-native

Trying to use socket.io-client with react-native (ios for now), so far connection / receiving server side events from client seems to be working fine. However I can't seem to emit any events from the client?

Client

```
var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        socket.on('ping', function(e) {
            console.log('Server emitted ping: ' + e);
            socket.emit('pong', 'hi server!');
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            console.log("disconnect");
        });
    });
```

Server(Node.js)

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('connected...');
  socket.on('pong', function (data) {
    console.log("Hmm?");
    console.log(data);
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Saying hello");
    socket.emit('ping', { message: 'Hello from server ' + Date.now() });

  }, 1000);
});
```

So from the server side, I see the logs

```
connected...
Saying hello
```

And in the client I see "Server emitted ping...", but the pong event doesn't seem to be doing anything? I tried catching all events on the server through solutions mentioned in StackOverflow, but it looked like no event was coming from the client. Any ideas?

Using latest RN version 0.31.

Also seeing this error when I first run the app in Xcode, could it be the reason?:

```
[warn][tid:main][RCTEventEmitter.m:52] Sending `websocketFailed` with no listeners registered.
```

Comment: have you tried just emitting outside socket.on?

Comment: i have. it doesn't seem to be emitting anything either...

Comment: try my answer on the server

Answer (score 0):

please try:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    ....
})
```

Comment: same issue :/ I have a feeling this is a bug with how react native is wrapping the emitter code

Comment: Let me try creating an RN app to quickly run this

Comment: Okay I will create an issue in github and reference this thread.

Comment: Just realized I don't actually need to emit stuff from client to server. I could do that with basic Ajax requests, just needed the server to client events :)

Comment: You may want to utilize bidirectional communication through sockets but it's up to you. :)

Comment: But would that apply even when I'm just trying to do something like updating a table on client side? At the moment I'm just emitting an "update" event from the POST server route where the table is updated.