# React Native - iOS Real Device - Socket IO Web Sockets not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, websocket, socket.io

I have ran into an issue with socket events not hitting the server. I have an application that uses SocketIO. The application works great when I use iOS Simulator. As soon as I try to run my app on a real device socket events are not hitting the server. This is the case in both localhost and the instance located on AWS.

When I press a button that should send a socket event to the server I get nothing in the console in Xcode. The only thing I can see is an initial error that seems to happen continuously as soon as the application is built and launched.

```
2019-01-30 07:12:38.533860-0800 Moder8[1033:191786] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C512.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2019-01-30 07:12:38.536864-0800 Moder8[1033:191786] [] nw_socket_connect [C512.2:1] connectx(7, [srcif=0, srcaddr=<NULL>, dstaddr=::1.8097], SAE_ASSOCID_ANY, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, SAE_CONNID_ANY) failed: [61: Connection refused]
2019-01-30 07:12:38.537119-0800 Moder8[1033:191786] [] nw_socket_connect [C512.2:1] connectx failed (fd 7) [61: Connection refused]
2019-01-30 07:12:38.537176-0800 Moder8[1033:191786] [] nw_socket_connect connectx failed (fd 7) [61: Connection refused]
2019-01-30 07:12:38.538112-0800 Moder8[1033:190902] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C512] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2019-01-30 07:12:38.538230-0800 Moder8[1033:190902] TCP Conn 0x282234840 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2019-01-30 07:12:40.115642-0800 Moder8[1033:191786] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C513.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2019-01-30 07:12:40.115716-0800 Moder8[1033:191786] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C514.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2019-01-30 07:12:40.116498-0800 Moder8[1033:191786] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C513.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2019-01-30 07:12:40.116561-0800 Moder8[1033:191786] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C514.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2019-01-30 07:12:40.116698-0800 Moder8[1033:190953] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C513] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2019-01-30 07:12:40.116715-0800 Moder8[1033:190953] TCP Conn 0x28221d380 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2019-01-30 07:12:40.116755-0800 Moder8[1033:190953] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C514] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2019-01-30 07:12:40.116768-0800 Moder8[1033:190953] TCP Conn 0x28221d2c0 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
```

The reason I am skeptical as to whether this has anything to do with the problem is because I get this same error when I use the Simulator and the socket events reach the server just fine.

***What I have done.***

I have searched Google and have read many references to related stuff including:

[React native socket io no events being emitted from client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068632/react-native-socket-io-no-events-being-emitted-from-client)

[Getting "socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused" python paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093568/getting-socket-error-errno-61-connection-refused-python-paramiko)

https://medium.com/@hr.hseyin_80381/8-steps-to-get-rid-of-error-nw-connection-get-connected-socket-connection-has-no-connected-handler-1bf622ca2332

[Can't connect to web socket react-native-meteor iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406222/cant-connect-to-web-socket-react-native-meteor-ios)

I almost feel like this is something ridiculously simple. I tried playing around with App Transport Security Settings but could not find anything that made a difference:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. iOS requires you to use the Mac IP address when connecting to localhost. I forgot to add my socket url into the env config file so it was pointing at localhost which obviously will not work for the localhost server instance or the one on AWS.